# Cannot find module 'firebase/app' in version 5.7.0

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, firebase-tools

I'm trying to build an angular project to be deployed on Firebase, but I can't run my `npm run build` or even `npm start` commands due to the following error.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,26):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
>   node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,79): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

I've gone through past questions, and have cleared my `node_modules` folder, as well as `package-lock.json` file, and reinstalled all the dependencies. I still keep getting this error.

Here's what I'm using in my app:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^5.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"particles.js": "^2.0.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
```

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: You have tried 'npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase
rm -rf node_modules
npm install' ?

Comment: Yup I have @zerocewl

Comment: Check if the last version of firebase works?

Comment: Hmm... Alright lemme try that. :) Thanks @zerocewl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to use angularFire2 which seems to be the angular firebase lib ;-)

[angularfire2 @ github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

[angularfire2 @ npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire)

This firebase [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1342) seems to be the same.

Additional this angularFire2 [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1iment?file=package.json) demo is working for me.

Edit:

Last but not least you might update your angular version (try to you use angular6 or 7).

Quote from the firebase issue:

> Also I noticed you are on Angular 5. Would you be able to upgrade to
>   angular6 or 7 and use the new cli to see if the problem persist?
>   AngularFire project doesn't seem to have this problem and they are on
>   angular6: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 1):

I changed angularFire2 to @angular/fire as per the suggestion from @zerocewl.

Not just at `npm install` but in `app.module.ts` as well. Installed `npm-check-updates` and
then I used `ncu -u` and `npm install` to update everything to the latest versions.

Solved a typescript issue by downgrading to version 3.1.6:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.2.0
>   but 3.2.2 was found instead.

Then it worked!